# WindDirection from point to point (or location)

Tags: android, geolocation, compass-geolocation

I have two points. Now is it possible to tell what windDirection one point is from another (eg Africa lays south of Europe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Location.bearingTo(Location) is what you're looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

You'd just need to map ranges of return values to north, east, etc.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, thnaks